# Webcam light remains ACTIVE when disconnecting from twilio video call

Tags: angular, twilio

I have developed video call application using angular 8 where participant joins in a video call and can see his local video turning webcam light ON. But when leaving or video call closing tab webcam light is not getting turned OFF. Library used for twilio video call is 2.0.0
I dont know what i am doing wrong.

On close button click I am calling a function in typescript as follows.

closeTimeEditDialog() {

```
this.room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
    const attachedElements = publication.track.detach();
    publication.track.stop();
        attachedElements.forEach(element => element.remove());
    });
    this.room.disconnect();
    this.messageService.showVideocallScreen = false;
```

}

```
room.once('disconnected', () => {
    this.room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
    publication.track.stop();
    const attachedElements = publication.track.detach();
    attachedElements.forEach(element => element.stop());
});
```

});

What I want is to disconnect from current video call room and turn off webcam light on close button click.